# Sufixo adicionado ao URL de site Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url

Boa tarde,

O meu site (construído na plataforma Wordpress), tem um problema em todos os URLs - aparece sempre um sufixo "?v=(codigo)".

http://www.carvalhocustom.com/

Já desativei todos os plugins e mudei de tema, mas o problema permanece.
Alguma dica?

Obrigado

Comment: Já verificou nas configurações dos `links permanentes`?

Comment: Também seria bom verificar o `.htaccess` do seu site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que pude pesquisar nos fóruns do **WordPress**, este é um erro conhecido, recorrente da configuração de Geolocalização do plugin [woocommerce](/questions/tagged/woocommerce) com a alguma configuração de *cache* ativa.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Fonte da pesquisa](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/weird-permalinks-2).

Importante frisar que isto não é um problema. Na verdade é uma configuração que melhora a forma como é feita a Geolocalização. Mas se não for agradável, é possível remover.

Comment: Obrigado Felipe,  era mesmo isso!